# Discrepancy in Initial Points between Neural ODE Graph and True Model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, deep-learning, neural-network, differential-equations

I am currently working on a project involving neural ODEs for dynamical system modeling in MATLAB. While implementing the neural network architecture, I have encountered a perplexing issue that I am seeking assistance with.
The problem I am facing is related to the initialization of the neural network within the Neural ODE framework. Specifically, when visualizing the graph of the neural network, I have noticed that it starts from a different initial point compared to the true initial point of the dynamical system model. This discrepancy is leading to deviations in the model's performance.
I have meticulously checked my code for any errors, and I am confident that there are no obvious bugs in the implementation. However, I have not been able to pinpoint the cause of this disparity in the initial points.
Thank you all for your time and support. I am eager to learn from your expertise and work towards resolving this puzzling problem.[NODE[Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Jrs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlI4x.jpg)

I want to solve my code problem